# Plesk 12 MYSQL database 1,8GB BACKUP need

Tags: mysql, database, backup, plesk

Can anyone give me instructions about export mysql database?

I always export database, but its size always will be 576MB, don't know why. It seems at phpmyadmin this 
database size is 1,8 GB.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 linux server at vps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log into mysq through the terminal:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p
```

Then use mysqldump to create a backup of your database as follows:

```
//Single database backup
mysqldump database_name > database_name.sql

//Multiple databases
mysqldump --databases database_name1 database_name2 > two_databases.sql

//Backup all your databases
mysqldump --all-databases > all_databases.sql
```

Or just use the mysql backup command below and pipe the output to gzip, then you will get the output as gzip file since your database is 1,8 GB:

```
mysqldump -u your_username -p your_password database_name | gzip -9 > backup_database_name.sql.gz
```

Comment: mysqldump database_name | gzip -9 > backup_database_name.sql.gz - got error 1045 access denied for user 'root' @ 'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect
Where can i put my password or howto in the command?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've updated the gzip command, it now has authentication, use the new command and enter your login information.

Comment: and where can i find the backupped file? i tried at my other server now, if it possible, i can try it at a big server at 0:00pm...

Comment: Have you checked in the MYSQL directory? : /var/lib/mysql/your_db_name? This is where your databases are stored.

Comment: Oh i see it at my home directory...
At my other server there are about 150-200 clients/minutes, i will see at google analytics, and can't make a backup or anything in during the day, trying to backup it at night, because it is impossible to stop the server, Thanks for instructions, hope it will be works fine...
And what about the import, i had to setup import file max 3gb, just can upload it clearly?

Comment: If my answer helped you, mark it as answered so other people with the same issue can find this more easily. If you want to import (restore) a database, use the following command:
 `mysql -u your_username -p your_password databasename_to_restore < backup_file.sql`

Comment: Im sorry, its my first question, where can i mark it answered?

Comment: it has backup 100mb all, not enough... :( any tip for backup?

Comment: mysqldump -u your_username -p database_name > backup.sql - only backup 487MB... Why?